# How can i import lzma archive from BLOB into angular project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blob, lzma

I have mysql database table with BLOB column, where lzma archive contains and I have angular project with php back-end. So how can I import lzma archive from database into my project?

I downloaded js library for compressing and decompressing lzma archives, but have an error "Incorrect argument" in decompress function.

PHP file:

```
if(isset($_GET['doc_id'])){

  $doc_id = $_GET['doc_id'];
  $arr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id = '$doc_id'") or die('error');
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($arr)){
      $array['id']=$row["id"];
      $array['body']=base64_encode($row["body"]);

}
echo json_encode ($array);
}
```

JS file

```
mainApp.factory('Editor',function($http){

  return{

    edit:function(id){
      var opt = {
        method:'GET',
        url:'assets/js/app/data/terms.php',
        params:{'doc_id':id}
      }
      $http(opt).then(function(response){
        my_lzma = new LZMA("assets/js/node_modules/lzma/src/lzma-d.js");
        my_lzma.decompress(response.data['body']),function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
      });
    },
    save:function(){

    },
    publicate: function(){

    }

  }
});
```

Maybe problem is in encoding or anything else?

Comment: You are sending the data encoded in base64, I guess you should base64 decode it first at the client before calling decompress

Comment: decoding this data gives null result @AlexBarroso

Comment: And you have sql injection vulnerability right over there: `$doc_id = $_GET['doc_id'];
  $arr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id = '$doc_id'") or die('error');`